# geometric distribution/ mean value

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, means

I consider the geometric distribution with $ P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$

I want to calculate: $ E[(X(X-1)] $

Solution is: $ E[(X(X-1)] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1) \cdot P(X=k)$

How do I get to that. By definition  holds: $$E[(X(X-1)] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1) \cdot P(X=k(k-1))$$ 
How do I compute that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "by definition"-statement is incorrect.
By definition we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k \cdot \mathbb{P}(X(X - 1) = k).
$$
Due to the [law of the unconscious statistician (LOTUS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) (this is formulated more generally for integrals, but if we choose our measure to be the counting measure, it becomes a sum) we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(h(X))
= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} h(x_n) \mathbb{P}(X = x_n)
$$
for any function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is the set of values the random variable $X$ takes.
Here, $h(x) := x(x-1)$.